# Add a citation reference without a bibliography entry in typst?

Tags: typst

Consider the following situation: My document contains several parts each of which requires a separate bibliography with distinct references. However, typst does not support multiple bibliographies yet. Hence, only the first part can use typst's built-in bibliography function.

As a workaround, I tried to create a bibliography for the latter parts manually. To this end, I use the `cite` function with `form: full` to mimic bibliography entries and put the bibliography together by hand. This works well but I cannot find a good solution to add inline references to my custom bibliography in the text. Apparently, `cite` is not useful here as it automatically creates a bibliography entry in the built-in bibliography from the first part, which is obviously not desired.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? What I would need is some function that simply inserts an inline reference with a certain citation style without the automatic creation of a bibliography entry.

The fallback would be to write a function that mimics the inline references in the desired style, which would be really ugly and cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple solution, more manual work

If you specify `#show bibliography: none`, you can load the full bibliography and hide the initial printout

```
#show bibliography: none
#bibliography("refs.bib")

= First Section
#cite(<plucked-string>, form: "full")

= Second Section
#cite(<plucked-string-extensions>, form: "full")
```

[image]

## More complex, but automatic

You can create a `state` that tracks all your citations from a section, and a function that prints those references on demand. Then, by flushing this state each time you create a heading, you can get automatically-populated sectional bibliographies!

```
#show bibliography: none
#bibliography("refs.bib")
// Keep track of all references, clearing every time a new heading is shown
#let section-refs = state("section-refs", ())

// Add bibliography references to the current section's state
#show ref: it => {
  it
  if it.element != none {
    // Citing a document element like a figure, not a bib key
    // So don't update refs
    return
  }
  section-refs.update(old => {
    old.push(it.target)
    old
  })
}

// Clear the previously stored references every time a level 1 heading
// is created
#show heading.where(level: 1): it => {
  section-refs.update(())
  it
}

#let section-bib() = locate(loc => {
  for target in section-refs.at(loc) {
    block(cite(target, form: "full"))
  }
})

= First Section
My reference @plucked-string and another @plot

#section-bib()

= Second Section
Another reference @plucked-string-extensions

#section-bib()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that's great! Thank you, I haven't considered using state for this purpose!

Comment: Minor remark: I had to modify your solution such that `#show cite` is used instead of `#show ref`. The reason for this is that I have to cite my sources using `#cite(("<label>"))` since my citation keys contain slashes, which is not compatible with the `@` syntax.